# Its possible to sort object array (Json Response) based on given key value

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Hi all I want to sort an object array (Json Response) by the given string. the following response I am getting via HTTP service.

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "reason": "Operation completed successfully.",
  "payload": [
    {
      "product_code": null,
      "indigent_kit": 0,
      "quan_limit": 0,
      "sort_order": 1040,
      "menu_prod_cat": "CLTH",
      "header_text": "CLOTHING",
      "product_desc": "CLOTHING",
      "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000366",
      "total_price": "0"
    },
    {
      "indigent_kit": 0,
      "quan_limit": 6,
      "sort_order": 1010,
      "product_desc": "TUBE SOCKS - 1 PAIR",
      "menu_prod_cat": "CLTH",
      "product_code": "9000",
      "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000366",
      "total_price": "2.05",
      "header_text": null
    },
    {
      "indigent_kit": 0,
      "quan_limit": 6,
      "sort_order": 1030,
      "product_desc": "T-SHIRT - SMALL",
      "menu_prod_cat": "CLTH",
      "product_code": "9005",
      "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000366",
      "total_price": "3.8",
      "header_text": null
    },
 {
      "indigent_kit": 0,
      "quan_limit": 6,
      "sort_order": 1060,
      "product_desc": "T-SHIRT - LARGE",
      "menu_prod_cat": "CLTH",
      "product_code": "9015",
      "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000366",
      "total_price": "3.8",
      "header_text": null
    },
    {
      "indigent_kit": 0,
      "quan_limit": 6,
      "sort_order": 1050,
      "product_desc": "T-SHIRT - XL",
      "menu_prod_cat": "CLTH",
      "product_code": "9020",
      "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000366",
      "total_price": "3.8",
      "header_text": null
    },
  ],
  "locked": false,
  "api": "get_menus"
}
```

now I want to sort this response by the `sort_order` key in angular with typescript.

any idea to do that? thanks

Comment: If you want answers in typescript, it's better provide type you desire.

Comment: yes i want do it in typescript. if you know the answer share with me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can simply use the function `Array.sort` in javascript

aka

```
const sortedarray = payload.sort((a,b) => a.sort_order - b.sort_order)
```

or in the case of your public variable

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]); this.dataSource.data = response.payload.filter(d => d.product_code != null && d.macs_menu_id === this.InmateMacMenu).sort((a,b) => a.sort_order - b.sort_order);
```

Comment: then can i store it into material table of angular. i want to store the sorted json response to the material table. below is my code  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);   this.dataSource.data = response.payload.filter(d => d.product_code != null  && d.macs_menu_id === this.InmateMacMenu);

Comment: after the filter you can happen the `.sort(...)`

Comment: sorry i cant get you

Comment: like that `public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]); this.dataSource.data = response.payload.filter(d => d.product_code != null && d.macs_menu_id === this.InmateMacMenu).sort((a,b) => a.sort_order < b.sort_order);`

Comment: ok i too typed this. let me try and update me thanks

Comment: i think the sorting function too not working. any idea to overcome this issue?

Comment: Hi thanks for your ideas, and i finally found the solution to work on that. i followed this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fc34aa/sort-json-object-array-based-on-a-key-attribute-in-javascrip/#:~:text=The%20above%20sort%20method%20would,to%20get%20the%20sorting%20implemented.   and seprate the payload array first & then used their function and now data get sorted and displayed in table too. thanks again

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feedback, i check your link and indeed the function i provided was not correct sorry i edit

Comment: yeah okay anyway i found solution from your idea only thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

try using `lodash` instead

`_.sortBy(data.payload, [({ sort_order }) => sort_order]);`